# How to use cursoring with get_timeline for many users?

Tags: r, twitter, rtweet

I am trying to get the timelines (last 3200 tweets) of a large number of Twitter users using the `rtweet` `get_timeline` function.

After a given number of requests, you need to stop for 15 minutes.

The problem is the following. Typically, the rate limit is reached halfway in a user timeline. Then, how do I resume downloading tweets from the last tweet I requested for that user?

Since some users have fewer than 3200 tweets, I cannot determine after how many users the rate limit will be reached.

I guess cursoring would be the solution here, but I can't wrap my head around how to use it.

This is a stripped-down example of the code that I am using.

```
i <- 1

# screen_names is a vector of Twitter screen_names
for (sn in screen_names){

   tryCatch(

    tl[i] <- get_timeline(sn, n = 3200),

    warning = function(w){

        Sys.Sleep(15 * 60)

    }

i <- i + 1

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adjusted from the package documentation...

```
i <- get_timeline(sn, n = 3200, retryonratelimit = T)
```